# integrating Jquery code into mvc core project properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to mvc core and Jquery.

I've created a project and trying to integrate Jquery into my cshtml file.

I have created a new .js file inside the wwwroot Js directory, and referenced the .js inside my cshtml file like

```
<script src="~/js/TourDetail.js"></script>
```

I have the following code in my TourDetail.js file

```
alert("Test");

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Test2");
});
```

so when the page is loaded it alerts the Test but does not alert "Test2"

also if I do something like it does not work either.

```
$("#something").click(function (e) {
alert("Test");});
```

am I missing anything? any help is appreciated I'm frustrated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jquery file add into top of the script file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are having issue with Jquery. Did you have referenced Jquery in `.cshtml` file ? If not then please put below jquery in `.cshtml` file.

**

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**